# Correct codable structure Swift 4 and KeyNotFound error

Tags: ios, swift, codable

**EDITED**

Hi I am using codable protocol for the first time: My JSON response (using POSTMAN) is:

```
[
{
    "FltId": "928",
    "Carrier": "AS",
    "Orig": "ANC",
    "Dest": "SEA",
    "CutOffTime": "40",
    "FltDirection": 0,
    "SchedDepTime": "2018-03-21T01:25:00",
    "EstDepTime": "2018-03-21T01:25:00",
    "SchedArrTime": "2018-03-21T05:43:00",
    "EstArrTime": "2018-03-21T05:43:00",
    "ActualTime": "",
    "OrigZuluOffset": "-8",
    "DestZuluOffset": "-7",
    "DestGate": "C15",
    "OrigGate": "",
    "CodeShares": [
        {
            "FltId": "",
            "Carrier": ""
        }
    ],
    "TailId": "251",
    "FleetType": "737-900R",
    "Status": "ON TIME"
},
{
    "FltId": "3422",
    "Carrier": "OO",
    "Orig": "BLI",
    "Dest": "SEA",
    "CutOffTime": "40",
    "FltDirection": 0,
    "SchedDepTime": "2018-03-21T05:00:00",
    "EstDepTime": "2018-03-21T05:00:00",
    "SchedArrTime": "2018-03-21T05:56:00",
    "EstArrTime": "2018-03-21T05:56:00",
    "ActualTime": "",
    "OrigZuluOffset": "-7",
    "DestZuluOffset": "-7",
    "DestGate": "C16",
    "OrigGate": "",
    "CodeShares": [
        {
            "FltId": "",
            "Carrier": ""
        }
    ],
    "TailId": "417",
    "FleetType": "CRJ-200",
    "Status": "ON TIME"
}]
```

I have created a codable structure of objects in my swift code and was wondering if it is correct:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let flights: [Flight]
}

struct Flight: Codable{
    let FltId, Carrier, Orig, Dest, CutOffTime, FltDirection, SchedDepTime, EstDepTime, SchedArrTime, EstArrTime, ActualTime, OrigZuluOffset, DestZuluOffset, DestGate, OrigGate, TailId, FleetType, Status: String, CodeShares:[CodeShare]
}
struct CodeShare: Codable {
    let FltId, Carrier: String
}
```

Can this be further fixed or improved? Furthermore what are coding keys? I get this weird error :

**failure(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(table_view_api.FlightWebService.Response.(CodingKeys in _954486EAAC5BB7DDCEFC26E493D69F38).flights, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0))], debugDescription: "No value associated with key flights (\"flights\").", underlyingError: nil)))**

Am I missing something?

Further more, I am making my webservice request with the proper auth header like:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Basic YWFnZTQxNDAxMjgwODYyNDk3NWFiYWNhZjlhNjZjMDRlMWY6ODYyYTk0NTFhYjliNGY1M2EwZWJiOWI2ZWQ1ZjYwOGM=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")



func getFlightData(for airportCode: String, minutesBehind:String, minutesAhead:String, completion: ((Result<[Response]>) -> Void)?) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "api.qa.alaskaair.com"
    urlComponents.path = "/1/airports/"+airportCode+"/flights/flightInfo"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "city", value: airportCode),
        URLQueryItem(name: "minutesBehind", value: minutesBehind),
        URLQueryItem(name: "minutesAhead", value: minutesAhead)

    ]

    guard let url = urlComponents.url else { fatalError("Could not create URL from components") }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Basic YWFnZTQxNDAxMjgwODYyNDk3NWFiYWNhZjlhNjZjMDRlMWY6ODYyYTk0NTFhYjliNGY1M2EwZWJiOWI2ZWQ1ZjYwOGM=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = responseError {
                completion?(.failure(error))
            } else if let jsonData = responseData {

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {

                    let posts = try decoder.decode(Array<Flight>.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion?(.success(posts))
                } catch {
                    completion?(.failure(error))
                }
            } else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Data was not retrieved from request"]) as Error
                completion?(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

can there be a issue with this?

Comment: What weird about it? The error is very clear: "No value associated with key flights"

Comment: but i am passing all the required values to the URL and url is getting built correctly too

Comment: oh got it! lemme make neccesary ammends

Comment: can you suggest a fix to the way I am making my codable objects looking at my JSON response?

Comment: Wait editing post. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to decode the JSON as a Response. That's your mistake. Given the structs you have defined and the JSON you have shown, your JSON evidently is (or is intended to be) an array of Flights, that is to say, `Array<Flight>.self`. So that is what you need to decode as.

Your Response struct is in fact apparently irrelevant to the JSON; you cannot decode as a Response, because the JSON is not a dictionary with a key `"flights"`. You can create a Response *manually* and set its `flights` *manually* to that result, but your Response struct, though it may come in handy for storage, has nothing to do with your JSON.

Comment: I have changed the decoder to decode Array<Flights> testing now

Comment: There may then appear _other_ problems, depending on your other structs, but that should get rid of the problem you originally _asked_ about. Please, do not post _different_ code from the one you asked the question about! That's very confusing to future readers.

Comment: Someone voted to close as "unclear what you are asking", in that case it is *expected* that OP edits and clarifies the question :)

Comment: Thanks and sorry about that :) I have posted my latest code. Debugging further

Comment: @MartinR Posting new code based on the _answer_ I gave, without making it clear that that's what we're seeing, does not clarify. In fact it makes my answer look weird, because I'm advising him to decode as `Array<Flight>` and he is doing that — but only because of my answer.